# Ошибка при запуске проекта Node.js

Tags: node.js

При запуске www.js вылетает ошибка, куда копать подскажите ? Могу предоставить app.js и www.js

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "/var/www/html/dist/index.hbs" in views directory "/var/www/html/сайт/dist-server/server/views"
at Function.render (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
at ServerResponse.render (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
at /var/www/html/сайт/dist-server/server/routes/index.route.js:19:22
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at router (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/сайт/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Comment: не знаю что это, но точно знаю, что кириллица в путях - дело гиблое.

Comment: @Alex Sazonov  это я для примера написал "сайт"

Answer (score 1):

я так понял он не находит index.hbs в /var/www/html/сайт/dist-server/server/views, так как ищет не его а /var/www/html/dist/index.hbs

Comment: дело в том что находится в /var/www/html/сайт/dist-server/server/views какого лешего он ищет его в /var/www/html/dist/index.hbs я не знаю( вот и задал вопрос так как не хватает мыслей

Comment: и еще, если я запускаю www.js из / а не из /var/www/html/сайт, то он выбивает ошибку ту что я написал

Answer (score 0):

ошибку устранил, запускал из корня системы /, через pm2 увидел exec cwd /, после удалил скрипт и создал из директории /var/www/html/сайт/ и теперь все запускается ! )))